# Why can't I update pipenv to latest version?

Tags: windows, pip, python-3.6, pipenv

If I check my version of pipenv it always shows 5.3.5, but I know there is newer version 11.0.2. How can I update it using pip?

```
C:\hello_world>pip search pipenv
dh-pipenv (0.1.1)                  - Shim between dh-virtualenv and pipenv
pipenv-package-requirements (0.2)  - Pipenv tools for requirements.txt
pipenv-tools (0.0.1)               - The missing tools for pipenv.
tox-pipenv (1.3.0)                 - A pipenv plugin for tox
pipenv-to-requirements (0.3.1)     - Generate requirements[-dev].txt from
                                     Pipfile using pipenv
pipenv (11.0.2)                    - Python Development Workflow for Humans.
  INSTALLED: 5.3.5
  LATEST:    11.0.2
```

When installing, all I get is:

```
C:\hello_world>pip install pipenv
Requirement already satisfied: pipenv in c:\users\administrator\appdata\roaming\
python\python36\site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv in c:\users\administrator\appdata\roam
ing\python\python36\site-packages (from pipenv)
Requirement already satisfied: semver in c:\users\administrator\appdata\roaming\
python\python36\site-packages (from pipenv)
Requirement already satisfied: pip in c:\python36\lib\site-packages (from pipenv
)
Requirement already satisfied: pip-tools>=1.9.0 in c:\users\administrator\appdat
a\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (from pipenv)
Requirement already satisfied: background in c:\users\administrator\appdata\roam
ing\python\python36\site-packages (from pipenv)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=36.3.0 in c:\users\administrator\appd
ata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (from pipenv)
Requirement already satisfied: pew>=0.1.26 in c:\users\administrator\appdata\roa
ming\python\python36\site-packages (from pipenv)
Requirement already satisfied: click>=6 in c:\users\administrator\appdata\roamin
g\python\python36\site-packages (from pip-tools>=1.9.0->pipenv)
Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\python36\lib\site-packages (from pip-to
ols>=1.9.0->pipenv)
Requirement already satisfied: first in c:\users\administrator\appdata\roaming\p
ython\python36\site-packages (from pip-tools>=1.9.0->pipenv)
Requirement already satisfied: futures in c:\users\administrator\appdata\roaming
\python\python36\site-packages (from background->pipenv)
Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv-clone>=0.2.5 in c:\users\administrator
\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (from pew>=0.1.26->pipenv)
Requirement already satisfied: pythonz-bd>=1.10.2 in c:\users\administrator\appd
ata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (from pew>=0.1.26->pipenv)
Requirement already satisfied: resumable-urlretrieve; python_version == "3.6" in
 c:\users\administrator\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (from pyth
onz-bd>=1.10.2->pew>=0.1.26->pipenv)
Requirement already satisfied: requests in c:\python36\lib\site-packages (from r
esumable-urlretrieve; python_version == "3.6"->pythonz-bd>=1.10.2->pew>=0.1.26->
pipenv)
```

The question is very simple, but mostly code to show you guy what I'm seeing. So this is basically filler text so that StackOverflow stops flagging that the question is mostly code. Please help.

Answer (score 64):

The right way to upgrade is upgrade:

```
pip install --upgrade pipenv
```