# Why doesn't "pip install --upgrade pipenv" upgrade pipenv?

Tags: pip, pipenv

I am trying to update pipenv on mac.  I followed [Why can't I update pipenv to latest version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49104330/why-cant-i-update-pipenv-to-latest-version) :

`pip install --upgrade pipenv`

It executes without errors (I get multiple `Requirement already satisfied`). Then I ran:

```bash
$ pipenv --version
pipenv, version 2020.6.2
```

According to https://pypi.org/project/pipenv/ I should get version 2023.2.18

Why isn't pipenv updating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem on mac.

`pipenv --version` command refers to `/usr/local/bin` but you upgraded `pipenv` on a location like `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages`. The second location is invoked with `pip show pipenv`. The first location can also be displayed with `which pipenv`.

After you upgrade the package, go to the `/usr/local/bin` and remove the `pipenv` link from there. Because it is a symlink referring to the location `/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2022.9.8/bin/pipenv`. In this Cellar directory, pipenv is an executable of version 2022.9.8.

This is what I did. When you run `pipenv --version` in the command line, you should get the latest version. And virtual environments can be created as before.

There could be other solutions but this one worked for me.